# Can you load an excel sheet with multiple tabs onto GoogleColab?

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I have a forecast I am working on and am wondering if I can load an excel sheet that contains multiple tabs with different sets of data onto GoogleColab.

For example, one is US sales, then another is CA Sales and so on. Or would I need to consolidate all tabs onto one file?

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is `drive.mount`. The rest are same as operation on your pc.

```py
import os
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
file_in = r'load.xlsx'  
path_base = r'/content/gdrive/My Drive/colab'  # colab Gdriver path    
fileData = os.path.join(path_base, file_in)
df1 = pd.read_excel(fileData, 'Sheet1')
df2 = pd.read_excel(fileData, 'Sheet2')
print(df1, "\n", df2)
```